# How to make Automatically change font size according to field block in zpl

Tags: zpl

I want to make automatically change or adjust the font size to increase or decrease defend on Field Block's size. For example, ^FB300,3,0,C^FDSurimi Salad, Kanikama, Cream cheeseSurimi Salad, Kanikama, Cream cheese^FS

^XA
^CF0,20
^FB300,3,0,C^FDSurimi Salad, Kanikama, Cream cheeseSurimi Salad, Kanikama, Cream cheese^FS

^XZ

Answer (score 0):

ZPL is a markup language so there is no logic you can really add to it.  Logic has to be done in the code that is sending the ZPL. An example in Javascript would look something like:

```
var listData = "Surimi Salad, Kanikama, Cream cheeseSurimi Salad, Kanikama, Cream cheese";
var fontwidth = 20;
var width = 300;
var lines = 3;
if (((listData.length * fontwidth)/width) > lines)
    fontwidth = fontwidth - 5;
var zpl = "^XA^A0N," + fontwidth + "," + fontwidth + "^FB" + width + "," + lines + ",0,C^FD" + listData + "^FS^XZ";
```

It won't be exact as most fonts are variable width, but it will get you closer to a fit.